# Python version problem/ Unable to import modules

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conda

I'm having trouble importing `keras`, `tensorflow` and `pyspark` even though I have used pip3 to install them. The version that I installed it with is Python 3.8.2. However, when I checked the Python version that Anaconda is running on, it is 3.7.7. Is there anyway I can install and import these packages properly given this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the basics of Conda. Don't use pip inside of a Conda environment unless absolutely necessary (see https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment). Don't use the base environment, it can only lead to trouble.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are installing keras and tensorflow to other python version. If you use pip3 install, it installs to Python 3.8.2 which is in a different environment from anaconda.

You can install this packages to your anaconda environment (which is a Python 3.7.7) like this:

```
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras
conda install pyspark
```

You can restart and import packages after the installation.

Comment: Agreed. I would further emphasize that Conda simply doesn't ever use aliases like `pip3` or `python3` because it expects that in an activate environment the Conda `pip` and `python` will have priority on the PATH. And really it is preferable to not have any system-level Python's on the PATH since it can lead to leakage into what should be isolated envs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to import the packages!

Comment: **Be careful!** If there is no activated environment, that will install the packages to the base environment, which you absolutely should not do.